# Using LINQ / GroupBy for a simple csv without class in C#

Tags: c#

I have csv file before processing in this format:

| Name | Spending | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 100 | Grocery |
| John | 50 | Dining |
| Michael | 55 | Carpooling |
| Steven | 15 | Grocery |
| Steven | 50 | Dining |

After processing , i want my csv file like this:

| Name | Spending | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 40 | Grocery |
| John | 20 | Dining |
| Michael | 55 | Carpooling |
| Steven | 13.864 | Grocery |
| Steven | 46.153 | Dining |

I need to manipulate the csv file based on the Total Spending amount for every Customer.

1. Group by similar header names and find the total spending.
2. if total spending is more than 60 for each Name, reset it to 60 except Carpooling ( can be multiple cases )
3. Reproportion the Spending's Subcategory proportionally eg John spend 2x in Grocery than Dinning. So when we reproportion it must be 40 for Grocery and 20 for Dinning.

4.Save the new values in a list and rebuilt the original "Spending" column in the csv.

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Query_csv
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Reading csv file
            string[] rawcsv = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Customer Spending.csv");

            //Empty array
            string[] customerSplitData;


            //Create an empty list for customerName,customerSpending,spendingCategory
            var customerName = new List<string>();
            var customerSpending = new List<double>();
            var spendingCategory = new List<string>();

            //Skip header and print all rows as you see in Notepad using for loop
            Console.WriteLine("Print each row on a new line:  ");
            for (int i = 1; i < rawcsv.Length; i++)
            {
                string lines = rawcsv[i];
                //Console.WriteLine(lines);

                customerSplitData = lines.Split(',');
                //Console.WriteLine(customerSplitData[0]);

                customerName.Add(customerSplitData[0]);

                double casted_spending = Convert.ToDouble(customerSplitData[1]);
                customerSpending.Add(casted_spending);


                spendingCategory.Add(customerSplitData[2]);
                
            }

            //Defining key
            var key = customerName;

            //Defining values
            var values = customerSpending;

            //For every key and values Using Query Syntax or GroupBY /LINQ
            var data = customerSplitData.GroupBy(entry => entry.key).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(entry => entry.value));

            //Creating a List of new customerSpending to save the reproportioned spending values after Querying
            var revisedcustomerspending = new List<double>();

            //Iterating through all the keys and Verifying the total
            var iSuccess = data.All(entry => entry.Value.Sum() > 60);
            if (iSuccess )
                //For every customer reproportion its spending amount by its original spending proportion
                Console.WriteLine("The Total customer spending is set to 60 and the spending subcategories are reproportion as original");

            else
                //For every customer do not reproportion but take the spending amount as it is original 
                Console.WriteLine("The Total customer spending is taken as default i.e less than or equal to 60 and the subcategory spending is not reproportioned");
        }

        //Save the reproportion values in the new CustomerSpending
        
        //Rebuild the csv string and save it as CSV


        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output as well?

Comment: @PeterCsala I have edited the code and added statement for expected output

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear. Let me try to ask in other way. Could you pleased edit your question by adding a new table with represents the new values after the processing?

Comment: @PeterCsala . The  new values are not to be added after processing to a new table, they will replace the old values from Spending table

Comment: Let me try it one more time :D Can we have two tables in your question? One before the processing and one after processing.

Comment: Hello sir, done! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using csv for experimenting I've created a List of [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0) like this:

```
var source = new List<(string Name, double Spending, string Category)>()
{
    ("John", 100, "Grocery"),
    ("John", 50, "Dining"),
    ("Michael", 55, "Carpooling"),
    ("Steven", 15, "Grocery"),
    ("Steven", 50, "Dining"),
};
```

With linq you can solve it with the following query:

```
var target =
    from @record in source
    group @record by @record.Name into customerRecords
    let totalSpending = customerRecords.Sum(r => r.Spending)
    let ratio = totalSpending < 60 ? 1 : 60 / totalSpending
    from customer in customerRecords
    select (customer.Name, customer.Spending * ratio, customer.Category);
```

- First let's group the records by their Name
- Then let's calculate the total spending
- From that we can calculate the ratio

  - If the total spending is less than 60 then the ratio will be 1
- Finally let's iterate through the groupings and emit a new tuple with the adjusted value

Let's print out:

```
foreach (var item in target) Console.WriteLine(item);
```

then this will be the output:

```
(John, 40, Grocery)
(John, 20, Dining)
(Michael, 55, Carpooling)
(Steven, 13.846153846153847, Grocery)
(Steven, 46.15384615384615, Dining)
```

---

**UPDATE** Convert to csv

If you don't want to use a 3rd party library for that then you can convert it like this:

```
var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();
csvBuilder.AppendLine("Name,Spending,Category");
foreach (var item in target)
{
    csvBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", item.Name, item.Item2, item.Category));
}
File.WriteAllText("output.csv", csvBuilder.ToString());
```

If you have the willingness to learn a 3rd party library then I would recommend the [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#writing-a-csv-file)

Comment: Hello sir, I have posted my answer based on your recommendation. But it still needs to be tweaked

Comment: @exdas What do you mean by *tweak*?

Comment: "Tweaked" to save the string "target" as csv.

Comment: @exdas I've updated my post please check it

Comment: Hello @Peter Csala, how can I add a new row or a column in LINQ using if conditions? Say whenever the spending is not 0 for Category "Dinning", I add a new row. Then I move the data from the Spending and Category to this new row

Comment: @exdas I don't truly understand your new request. What should the new row contain? How should I calculate its values?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
namespace Query_csv
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Reading csv file
            string[] rawcsv = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Customer Spending.csv");


            //Creating a list of Value Tuples
            List<(string Name, double Spending , string Category)> customer_vtuples_list = new List<(string, double, string)>();

            //Skip header and print all rows as you see in Notepad using for loop
            //Console.WriteLine("Print each row on a new line:  ");
            for (int i = 1; i < rawcsv.Length; i++)
            {

                string[] customerSplitData = rawcsv[i].Split(',');
                //Console.WriteLine(rawcsv[i]);


                double convertedcustomerSpending = Convert.ToDouble(customerSplitData[1]);

                customer_vtuples_list.Add((customerSplitData[0], convertedcustomerSpending, customerSplitData[2]));
            }


            for( int v = 0; v < customer_vtuples_list.Count; v++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld!");
                //Console.WriteLine(customer_vtuples_list[v]);
                //Console.WriteLine(customer_vtuples_list[v].Name);
            }

            //Creating a list of new target values
            var target = from @record in customer_vtuples_list group @record by @record.Name into customerRecords let totalSpending = customerRecords.Sum(r => r.Spending) let ratio = totalSpending < 60 ? 1 : 60 / totalSpending from customer in customerRecords select (customer.Name, customer.Spending * ratio, customer.Category);

            foreach (var item in target) Console.WriteLine(item);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `customerName`, `customerSpending` and `spendingCategory` collection, since you store all data inside your `customer_vtuples_list` variable

Comment: I updated my code above